# Convert null fields of String data type after CSV import

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a csv file with data

```
id,amount,comments
"1",5.0,"cccc"
"2",4.0,"cccc"
"3",,"cccc"
```

now when i import this csv in mongodb the amount field for the last object got imported as a String with "" as a value.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f26dc2e5ec3103f7123e65"),
    "id" : 1, 
    "amount" : 5, 
    "comments" : "cccc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f26dc2e5ec3103f7123e66"), 
    "id" : 2,
    "amount" : 4,
    "comments" : "cccc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f26dc2e5ec3103f7123e67"),
    "id" : 3, 
    "amount" : "",
    "comments" : "cccc"
}
```

But i want this field in Double with value 0.0
How to achieve this in mongodb?

Comment: `mongoimport` will not do it by itselff and is basically not designed as a tool to do this sort of thing. If you want to substitute values then either replace them in the input file first or update the values "after" you import them. If it's your "own code" that is doing the import, then simply make your code substitute the values.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to match the "strings" in the `"amount"` field using the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator in an [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) statement and [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) the value to `0` instead.

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "amount": { "$type": 2 } },
    { "$set": { "amount": 0 } },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

The [`"multi"`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) option applies the update to every document that matches the condition

You could alternately just match on the empty string `""`:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "amount": "" },
    { "$set": { "amount": 0 } },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

But in your case, unless you have other writes happening on the collection then it's pretty safe to assume that any string is acceptable to overwrite.